# When we say extract a causal DAG from a multivariate time series, what does it actually mean?

Tags: time-series, causality, granger-causality, dag

I am from CS background and as part of my PhD, I am doing a project where I need to used causal inference to construct a causal DAG (directed acyclic graph) from a multivariate time series data. As I am new to causal inference, I am not understanding whether it is possible to get a causal DAG from a time series data like from a tabular data (where I can use algorithms like FGES to find out the causal relationship between features). I have referred the following papers but I am still having difficulty to understand what a causal relationship in a multivariate time series means. Does it mean to have relationship between multiple features or how the past value of the feature can affect the future value of the feature.

1. https://paperswithcode.com/paper/neural-granger-causality-for-nonlinear-time
2. https://paperswithcode.com/paper/amortized-causal-discovery-learning-to-infer

Answer (score 2):

They are about the past affecting the future, which makes the problem easier. Both papers' equations 1 write the current vector in terms of previous vectors. The second paper also explicitly says "no instantaneous edges". Given that edges are also assumed not to go backwards in time, this means you know the direction of any edge.

Given unlimited data from the same DAG and assuming no unmeasured confounding and some sort of ergodicity property and some bound on the maximum causal lag, you can (in principle) estimate all the conditional independence relations where some variable at time $t$ is independent of the rest of the past conditional on some set of past variables.

These conditional independence relations plus the edge directions plus some other assumptions like faithfulness give you the DAG (in principle)

In practice it's obviously hard.  As well as all the usual problems with 'no unmeasured confounding', you need to measure the process frequently enough that you see any change in a cause at a time point earlier than you see its effects, to ensure the arrow of time flies in the right direction.  On the other hand, the number of potential edges in the DAG is exponential in the number of measurements up to the maximum lag, so if you measure too often you'll need completely infeasible amounts of data or very strong sparseness assumptions.

Comment: So that means there is no easy way to get a DAG via using software like TETRAD where I input a time series data like stock exchange data and get a DAG output?

Comment: Also, in case of multivariate time series data, is it possible to establish causal relationship between two features like in tabular data?

Answer (score 0):

### You can (most likely) not apply standard DAG learning algorithms to time series data

A way to think about DAG learning algorithms that are not tailored to time series (such as FGES) is this: All variables are all observed at an initial time $t_0$. Then you let the system variables interact until they have reached an equilibrium at time $t_1$, where you measure the variables again. If the starting value of one variable affects the equilibrium value of another one, they are causally connected. The causal relationship between the variables simultaneously encodes the dependency between start and equilibrium, which are the only time steps that exist.

This logic breaks once you have a time series where causal networks iteratively relate past states to future states through Granger causality.
So you are correct in assuming that such algorithms most likely won't be applicable for your case.

### Note of caution

Causal structure learning algorithms tend to come with heavy assumptions (e.g. additive noise, no unobserved variables, acyclicity, ...) and have trouble returning useful results at the best of times (even FGES just returns a CPDAG that may not be correct even if all assumptions are met). So just beware that causal structure learning from multivariate time series is a tall order!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Runge's work with climate time series data to get a good starting point

https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=wtXVvuUAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=ao